# UNITY 3D - Camera perspective shows objects moving the wrong way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

while following some guides to make an object move, I have this issue.

So, all objects on the scene are 0, 0, 0, on rotation except for the camera. The camera, then is  0, 180, 0. The script says - for a object to move to the left
:

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * (ScrollSpeed * Time.deltaTime));//access transform component and moves it left by 20 times the frame rate
}
```

So technically it moves left, but the camera perspective is at 180 degrees to look at the game from the front. So is my only solution to rotate the platform on Y to match the perspective to make it in reverse so when working on things I dont have to keep using negative numbers to do the opposite of the actual scene?

Comment: what's keeping you from having the gameobject's rotations being (0,180,0) as well? That way the object's relative directions match those of the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Vector3` static variables which are define in the world space, you can use the `transform` of the Camera, so the moving directions are depending on the Camera. That is to say in your case:

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(
    -Camera.main.transform.right * (ScrollSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

Notice the `-` in front of `Camera.main.transform.right`, the opposite of the right direction is the left direction ;-)

If you have several Cameras in your scene, use a reference to the Camera you want instead of `Camera.main`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

So the original scene itself was 0, 0, 0, but I needed to play the scene -180 on the Y axis and face the camera at 0, 0, 0, this way the only thing rotated is the design of the background.